# Uncaught TypeError: systems[name] is not a constructor

Tags: laravel, vite, aframe

I am developing a Web AR app using laravel, vite and aframe.
My problem is that when I run the `npm run build` command, the scripts are added as `type="module"`.
According to the a-frame document: [script has to be included before <a -scene> because A-Frame registers custom HTML elements which must be defined before is attached or else will do nothing.](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/guides/building-a-basic-scene.html#starting-with-html)

But `type="module"` causes the script to be loaded after `<a-scene>` and this causes this problem:
`Uncaught TypeError: systems[name] is not a constructor`

Is there a way to disable this default behavior of vite or any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.